# Scroll view hiding top radio buttons

Tags: android, xml

I have a Navigation drawer activity in my app and i have a some fragments there. In one fragment i have a Scrollview and inside that i have radio button group. Radio buttons are added dynamically from the data getting from database. Problem is the scrollview is hiding 2 radio buttons in the top of the app
This is the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nimesha.delivery.Curjob_fragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/naviBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signoutbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/naviBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how i populate radio button group

```
   for (DataSnapshot jobSnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = jobSnap.getKey();
                    Double lat = jobSnap.child("lat").getValue(Double.TYPE);
                    Double longi =jobSnap.child("long").getValue(Double.TYPE);
                    Log.d(TAG, key + " " + lat + " " + longi);

                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
                    radioButton.setLayoutParams
                            (new RadioGroup.LayoutParams
                                    (RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    radioButton.setText("Radio Button #" + lat);
                    radioButton.setId(count);

                    //add it to the group.
                    radiogroup.addView(radioButton, count);
                    count += 1 ;
                }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Qfj.jpg

There should be some more radio buttons on top

Comment: are they hidden, or not added to the group?

Comment: They are added, but some of the buttons are placed behind the activity title bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/naviBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/naviBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Navigate"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signoutbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The blue background hides the problem, but at the same time it hides my activity title bar, so this is not what i'm looking for

Comment: That background was not intentional, it was for testing purpose only

Comment: Figured out the problem. Used linear layout. Now it looks like what i expect. Thanks